# Pandas Dropping all but last item in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas table where there is a list in one column:

```
id | values
1    [100, 200]
2    [101, 500]
3    [102, 250]
```

I want to drop the first item in the list so that I am left with the last value without it being in a list. Such as:

```
id | values
1    200
2    500
3    250
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) a lambda to access the last element:

```
In [5]:
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
df

Out[5]:
   id  value
0   1    200
1   2    500
2   3    250
```